# Creating raster stack using R?

Tags: r, modis, mosaic

I have 300 `.tiff` files, that i need to create raster stack of them. Can you please help me with R code for that?

I can do in Arcgis, Envi, R. I have tried:

```
setwd("F:\\MODIS\\Modis EVI\\HDF8 EVI")

list.files(path="F:\\MODIS\\Modis EVI\\HDF8 EVI", pattern = ".tif")

tifs <- list.files(path="F:\\MODIS\\Modis EVI\\HDF8 EVI", pattern = ".tif")
stackSave(tifs,"hdf8_EVI.TIF")
```

and

```
setwd("F:\\MODIS\\Modis EVI\\HDF8 EVI")
raster_stack=list.files(getwd(), pattern="tif$", full.names=FALSE)
for(i in raster_stack) { assign(unlist(strsplit(i, "[.]"))[1], raster(i)) }
```

Both didn't work!

Comment: Please take the community [tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) and edit your question to include what exactly it is that you are having problems with and what you have tried, including code snippets.

Comment: You may also find this post from Stack Overflow useful to produce a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). This will greatly help us recreate your problem and test solutions.

Comment: Also, describe what "didn't work" means. Did you get an error? If so, include it in your question. If not, what behavior did you get vs. what you expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
fs <- list.files(path="F:\\MODIS\\Modis EVI\\HDF8 EVI", pattern = "tif$", full.names = TRUE)
library(raster)
s <- raster::stack(fs)
writeRaster(s, "hdf8_EVI.TIF")
```

I have no idea what `stackSave` is. Please read about asking questions here and look into the basics of the `raster` package. Don't use `assign`, and don't use `setwd` - both are really bad practice for general use.

EDIT: just learnt what `raster::stackSave` is - it's awesome. It's not for writing multi-band TIF files.